# Connection Eviction strategy in Http Connection Pooling in Java

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to implement a http connection pooling in java for a web service. The service will receive a request and then call other http services.

```
public final class HttpClientPool {
 private static HttpClientPool instance = null;
 private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager manager;
 private IdleConnectionMonitorThread monitorThread;
 private final CloseableHttpClient client;

 public static HttpClientPool getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) {
   synchronized(HttpClientPool.class) {
    if (instance == null) {
     instance = new HttpClientPool();
    }
   }
  }
  return instance;
 }

 private HttpClientPool() {
  manager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
  client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(manager).build();
  monitorThread = new IdleConnectionMonitorThread(manager);
  monitorThread.setDaemon(true);
  monitorThread.start();
 }

 public CloseableHttpClient getClient() {
  return client;
 }
}


class IdleConnectionMonitorThread extends Thread {
 private final HttpClientConnectionManager connMgr;
 private volatile boolean shutdown;

 IdleConnectionMonitorThread(HttpClientConnectionManager connMgr) {
  super();
  this.connMgr = connMgr;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  try {
   while (!shutdown) {
    synchronized(this) {
     wait(5000);
     // Close expired connections
     connMgr.closeExpiredConnections();
     // Optionally, close connections
     // that have been idle longer than 30 sec
     connMgr.closeIdleConnections(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
   }
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
   //
  }
 }

 void shutdown() {
  shutdown = true;
  synchronized(this) {
   notifyAll();
  }
 }
}
```

1. As mentioned in [Connection Management](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e418) doc for Connection Eviction strategy instead of using a `IdleConnectionMonitorThread` what if I use `manager.setValidateAfterInactivity`. What are the pros & cons of the above two approach?
2. Is the above Http Connection Pool implementation correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `#setValidateAfterInactivity` set to a positive value persistent connections will get validated upon lease request. That is, stale and non-reusable connections will not get automatically evicted from the pool until an attempt is made to re-use them.

Running a dedicated thread that iterates over persistent connections at the specified time interval and removes expired or idle connections from the pool ensures proactive connection eviction at the cost of an extra thread and slightly higher pool lock contention.

Comment: In the link I posted in my question https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e418. It is mentioned `The stale connection check is not 100% reliable. The only feasible solution that does not involve a one thread per socket model for idle connections is a dedicated monitor thread`. So does this hold for `setValidateAfterInactivity` as well?

Comment: Yes, it does. Given that the stale connection check is relatively expensive HttpClient as of version 4.4 no longer checks every connection but only those that has been inactive for a certain period of time

Comment: If I am getting correctly setting `setValidateAfterInactivity` will run the stale check if a connection is idle for that many ms as specified in `setValidateAfterInactivity`, even then it is not reliable. If we want complete reliability then we should use the `IdleMonitorThread` approach?

Comment: There is no such thing as complete reliability with HTTP protocol as HTTP does not have delivery guarantees by design. One must always be prepared to re-try  / re-execute requests in case of a failure (provided those requests are considered safe). Connection validation / eviction merely helps reduce the number of retries

Comment: yeah right.  Can you please explain what does this statement mean `The only feasible solution that does not involve a one thread per socket model for idle connections is a dedicated monitor thread` as posted in the first comment?

Comment: If you have, say, 100 connections and 5 worker threads, max 5 connections can be active at any given time. 95 would be idle (unable to react to connection termination by the opposite endpoint). For all 100 connections to be able to react to I/O events simultaneously it would require 100 threads

Answer (score 1):

In HttpClient 4.5.3, `manager.setValidateAfterInactivity` has a defult value of 2000 which is 2 seconds. So I would suggest not to use a `IdleConnectionMonitorThread` unless you want the application to validate inactive connections and clean up at the same time.